# Automapper - aftermap weird behaviour

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using automapper for creating instance of aggregates roots from my CQRS command.

Something like that.

```
 var managerRegisterCommand = new ManagerRegisterCommand()
            {
                ManagerEmail = emailDto
            };

 var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<UserAggregateProfile>());
 var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
 var managerAggregateRoot = mapper.Map<ManagerRegisterCommand,ManagerAggregateRoot>(managerRegisterCommand);
```

At this moment i have UserAggregateRoot and ManagerAggregateRoot, both classes inherit from AggregateRoot when i'm creating instance of UserAggregateRoot from UserRegisterCommand using automapper, instance is created correct, UserCreatedEvent is emited.

```
 var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<UserAggregateProfile>());
 var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

 var userAggregateRoot = mapper.Map<UserRegisterCommand,UserAggregateRoot>(userRegisterCommand);
 var eventsList = userAggregateRoot.GetUncommittedChanges().ToList();
 eventsList.Count.Should().Be(1); // <- it's works correct, 1 event is emitted
```

There is my map config.

```
 CreateMap<UserRegisterCommand,UserAggregateRoot>().AfterMap((src,dest,context) =>
            {
                var userId = context.Mapper.Map<UserId>(src.Id);
                var name = context.Mapper.Map<Name>(src.Name);
                var login = context.Mapper.Map<Email>(src.Login);
                var password = context.Mapper.Map<Password>(src.Password);
                var birthDate = context.Mapper.Map<BirthDate>(src.BirthDate);
                dest = new UserAggregateRoot(userId,login,password,name,birthDate);
            });
```

But problem is with my ManagerAggregateRoot, instance created through automapper, have 0 events in list, event list is empty, but when im creating managerAggregateRoot using new operator outside automapper is created correct.

I have also mapper configuration, something like that

```
CreateMap<ManagerRegisterCommand,ManagerAggregateRoot>().AfterMap((src,dest,context) =>
            {
                var managerId = context.Mapper.Map<ManagerId>(src.Id);
                var email = context.Mapper.Map<Email>(src.ManagerEmail);
                dest = new ManagerAggregateRoot(managerId,email);
            });



    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<UserAggregateProfile>());
    var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
    var managerAggregateRoot = mapper.Map<ManagerRegisterCommand,ManagerAggregateRoot>(managerRegisterCommand);
    var eventList = managerAggregateRoot.GetUncommittedChanges().ToList();
    eventList.Count.Should().Be(1); // <- here i should have 1 event but is 0, when creating instance ManagerAggregateRoot without automapper it is 1.
```

It's a problem with automapper, because when creating instance of ManagerAggregateRoot class event is emited. But when i'm creating this instance using automapper, automapper returns empty list of events. It should be same behaviour as UserAggregateRoot, but is not.

Comment: I *strongly* suggest reading [AutoMapper's Design Philosophy](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/). You'll find it has very little to do with what you're trying to do. `AutoMapper works because it enforces a convention.` There's no sign of that convention here

Comment: See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html.